# How to configure common folder as pip cache for across all users?

Tags: package-management, python, cache

Situation:

- I have multiple users with their home folders under `/home`.
- All of them are added to a group, e.g., `pipcache`, with read-write permissions on a common folder (e.g., `/home/pipcache`).

Yet, I'm unable to make use of the cache folder: if user-a downloads `xyz` package, it gets cached, but when user-b later downloads the same `xyz` package, it doesn't use the cached version, but re-downloads it. Both users use the same environment (Python=3.10 and pip=23.1.2).

Here's the setup for group and folder:

```bash
groupadd pipcache
mkdir /home/pipcache
chgrp -R pipcache /home/pipcache
chmod g+w /home/pipcache
```

And here's how I'm setting up the users:

```bash
useradd -m user-a
adduser user-a pipcache
```

I don't think this is such a rare problem I'm facing and still I wasn't able to find anything online except:

[File permissions for cache shared between multiple users #11012](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11012).

Comment: What happens if you install the pip packages as "sudo". (I usually do this on embedded devices). The packages will be installed for everyone to see and use. Mind that you should only install packages this way that will not interfere with existing ones

Comment: Make sure all users have also write access to all files.